# Material-UI XGrid: Can I control initial sort order of rows? Why doesn't apiRef.getAllRowIds() no longer respect sort order?

Tags: material-ui

I recentely upgraded @material-ui/x-grid to version 4.0.0-alpha.12 (from alpha.6) in the hopes of resolving some bugs with the grid. Unfortunately this caused more issues than it helped.

Previously the grid would render items in the order they were defined in the array of "rows" provided.
For instance if you provided an array that looks like this:

```
const rows = [{ id: 10 }, { id: 0 }, { id: 5 }];
```

The grid would render in that order. In alpha 12 the grid seems to automatically order by 'asc' when initially rendering the rows. Is there a way to retain the order of items as they were provided?

Also previously in version alpha 6, calling `apiRef.getAllRowIds()` would give an array of Ids from rendered rows top to bottom, respecting the current sort order of the grid. Now in version alpha 12 the function seems to return the Ids in the initial render order always, disregarding any manual sorting. The use case I'm trying to solve is "select the top X rows in the grid" where X is a user input, whilst respecting the current sort order of the grid.

Comment: The second part about selecting the top X items can be solved by accessing the internal state via apiRef.state.sorting.sortedRows. However anything not documented by the material team should be considered private..

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. More info can be found here:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/753